# Make cyclical slider with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm really new in JavaScript. I want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cur = -1;

    //while (true) {
    //    $('.slider .cadr').eq(cur).fadeOut();
    //    cur += 1;
    //    $('.slider .cadr').eq(cur).fadeIn();
    //    
    //    delay(); // how do I do this?
    //}    
});​
```

So how do I delay? Please fix my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpyZF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There something like `setInterval` function instead of it. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wxkhH/

Syntax:

```
setInterval(function, number);
```

And you should do

```
el1.fadeOut(function () {
  el2.fadeIn();
});
```

Other way they will start at the moment.

And if you want it goes cyclical, then use `cur = (cur + 1) % 4;`

Comment: Thanks :), I mean you have written `setTimeout`, I think you mean _setInterval_.